# Setting up Ubuntu for gaming

Tags: games

I was wondering if anyone had a set script for installing everything for gaming in Ubuntu. I tried with Linux mint and I crashed my laptop top. I have two laptop’s set up with Ubuntu 20.04. A 2013 HP 2000 notebook with a AMD Readeon, and a 2009 MacBook with a nvidia card.

Comment: This not really an answerable question.  There is no such thing as a "script for installing everything for gaming" because what you need to configure depends on each individual game. For example, installing an open source chess game from the software center is going to be different than installing a game from the linux steam client.  Some game devs don't make their software compatible with Ubuntu, which can make it complicated to run the software, with each game having its own particular quirks and dependencies.

Comment: You can ask here about how to install a particular game if you still have unanswered questions after searching and researching how to install that game on Ubuntu.  I'd advise against running some script you found on the internet unless you can read the script and fully understand exactly what it does and the consequences of running those actions and knowing how to reverse those actions if needed.

Comment: Thanks I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to learn a little more about it and game on pc. Thanks for your advice I will do some digging and researching on that.